# How to calculate the average of the 10 farthest right cells in a row with a value

Tags: excel, average

I have a spreadsheet with scores by player, tournaments in chronological order.  I want to get an average of their score for the most recent 10 rounds (so the farthest 10 to the right that have a value in them, blanks would be excluded).  The blank cells are throwing a monkey wrench in the whole thing.  How can I accomplish this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSDLo.png)

Comment: what have you tried? show us your formulas so far

Comment: This is code that I stole from another post that didn't work so good:=(AVERAGE(OFFSET(C3,0,LARGE(IF(C3:BF3>0,COLUMN(C3:BF3),""),10)-COLUMN(C3),1,COLUMN(BF3)+1-LARGE(IF(C3:BF3>0,COLUMN(C3:BF3),""),10))))

Answer (score 0):

If placer name is in cell B1 and the scores commence in cell C1 and then D1, E1 etc, then this will work in cell A1:

```
={SUM(INDEX(C6:ZZ6,LARGE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C6:ZZ6)),COLUMN(C6:ZZ6)-CELL("COL",C6:ZZ6)+1),10)):INDEX(C6:ZZ6,COLUMNS(C6:ZZ6)))}
```

It will add the last 10 non-blank cells

It is an array formula, so you need to press ctrl-shift-enter

Comment: It looks like this will calculate the last ten cells, is there a way to tweak this so it will only calculate the last ten cells with values (exclude blanks)?

Comment: Fixed for the blanks issue

Comment: You will be inscribed for blessing in the book of life.  Thank you so much.